# RESTful-compliant "create page" URL

Tags: rest, http

I have a question about HTTP method mapping based on RESTful architecture. This is a really widely discussed topic, I know, but I can't find a useful example, unfortunately.

What I'm interested in is how I should map "create new" page to an HTTP request/URL. Most web-application use AJAX with popups or something similar, so there's no difference between a list of resources(users/) and a creation of a new user(users/), and hence the creation is not bookmarkable, which is justifiable, for sure, since in general why would one want to bookmark a page with a bunch of input fields if they will be empty anyways and all the data should be filled from scratch.

Incidentally, SO uses "questions/ask". What do you use/prefer and what is more RESTful-compliant in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly use `GET /users/new` to serve creation form and `POST /users/new` to submit the form

Comment: Thank you, joozek! That's probably what I will resort to.